# Pandas - Get the first n rows if a column has a specific value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that has 5 columns including User and MP.

I need to extract a sample of n rows for each User, n being a percentage based on User (if User has 1000 entries and n is 5, select the first 50 rows and and go to the next User. After that I have to add all the samples to a new DataFrame. Also if User has multiple values on the column MP, for example if the user has 2 values in the column MP, select 2.5% for 1 value and 2.5% for the other.

Somehow my logic isn't that good(started with the first step, without adding the logic for multiple MPs)

```
df = pd.read_excel("Results/fullData.xlsx")
dfSample = pd.DataFrame()
uniqueValues = df['User'].unique()
print(uniqueValues)
n = 5
for u in uniqueValues:
    sm = df["User"].str.count(u).sum()
    print(sm)
    for u in df['User']:
        
        

        sample = df.head(int(sm*(n/100)))
        #print(sample)
        dfSample.append(sample)
print(dfSample)
dfSample.to_excel('testFinal.xlsx')
```

Comment: Check out `pandas`'s `.groupby` and `.sample` methods.

Comment: Hi, u can user df.iloc[pd.data.value == value] :) examples..

Answer (score 1):

Check Below example. It is intentionally verbose for understanding. The column that solve problem is **"ROW_PERC"**. You can filter it based on the requirement (50% rows or 25% rows) that are required for each **USR/MP**.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'USR':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'MP':['A','A','A','A','B','B','A','A'],"COL1":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
df['USR_MP_RANK'] = df.groupby(['USR','MP']).rank()
df['USR_MP_RANK_MAX'] = df.groupby(['USR','MP'])['USR_MP_RANK'].transform('max')

df['ROW_PERC'] = df['USR_MP_RANK']/df['USR_MP_RANK_MAX']
df
```

Output:

[image]